# How to run html file on web server package on Oracle cloud Apex

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-cloud-infrastructure, scorm

I am hosting a SCORM package (html file with dependent JavaScript files) on a Oracle cloud compute instance web server. I am using Oracle Cloud Apex as the user interface application. When pointing an iframe's source to the SCORMS main html file on the webserver, chrome sees it as a violation of the "cross origin" policy. This is due to the html file's attempt to load the required JavaScript files it needs to navigate a learning course.
Is there anyway to "trust" this webserver? Or a different way I can store these SCORM packages on Oracle cloud that would not violate a browsers security policies?

I attempted to enter my web servers address in the apex proxy server application setting, hoping the web server would work as a source for my iframe region, but nothing changes.

I thought about loading these html and javascript files to static application files, but this would prove to be impossible to manage and administrate with the amount of files involved